# How to Access Alfresco Repository through JCR API

Tags: alfresco, jcr

I am trying to access Alfresco Repository through JCR APIs and SpringFramework by following this Link: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Introducing_the_Alfresco_Java_Content_Repository_API.

### IDE: Eclipse Galileo

```
System.out.println("Initialising Repository...");
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:alfresc/application-context.xml");
    //ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(); 

    Repository repository = (Repository)context.getBean("JCR.Repository");

             // display information about the repository
     System.out.println("Repository Description...");
             String  [] keys = repository.getDescriptorKeys();
             for (String   key : keys)
             {
                 String   value = repository.getDescriptor(key);
                 System.out.println(" " + key + " = " + value);
         }
```

---

### and getting this exception:

```
 Initialising Repository...
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyValueCache' defined in class path resource [alfresco/cache-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'disableSharedCache'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${system.cache.disableImmutableSharedCaches}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tcs.alfresco.WikiExample.main(WikiExample.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean' for property 'disableSharedCache'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${system.cache.disableImmutableSharedCaches}]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${system.cache.disableImmutableSharedCaches}]
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
    ... 17 more
```

---

I have also tried alfresco SDK. But getting the same error.
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK_4.0

My alfresco's copy is correct as i am able to connect to repository through CMIS. Please Help.

Thanks
Rishi

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same classpath for both? That exception suggests you might be missing some of the context xml files or properties files in your JCR setup

Comment: you are trying to load applicationContext.xml file form folder alfresc ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:alfresc/application-context.xml") Is it available on class path?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I also had this doubt, so i removed my older copy of Alfresco, Installed a fresh one and again tried the above code, but the issue is still in there. #mitpatoliya: yes, its there in classpath. I have checked it more than once.

Comment: What about things like your `alfresco-global.properties` file - is that definitely on your classpath when running as JCR?

Comment: Support for JCR seems to have been dropped because it's no longer listed in the [API guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-api-intro.html).